# How to have frame for figure expand inwards?

Tags: floats

How can I have a red frame that expands inwards? For example, the code below generates a frame that expands outwards. How can I have it expand inwards so it doesnt take any extra space beyond the figure? For example `\frame(color=(1,0,0),width=0.1mm,expand_inwards=True){\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}\\
    \frame{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are funny interactions between `\fbox` and `\includegraphics`, so my solution is to typeset the graphics with zero width and an `\fbox` with the appropriate dimensions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphics}{O{}m}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.4mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \fbox{\rule{0pt}{\ht0}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.12\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\frameincludegraphics[width=0.12\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I used `0.4mm` just to make the frame more visible.

[image]

You can add a trailing color optional argument, if you want colored frames.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphics}{O{}mO{black}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.4mm}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  {\color{#3}\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\ht0}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.12\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\frameincludegraphics[width=0.12\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\frameincludegraphics[width=0.12\textwidth]{example-image-a}[red!60]

\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: may i know how to change the colors? i need 2 different colors so I can create 2 variables \frameincludegraphics1 and \frameincludegraphics2 but how do i change the colors for these boxes? I tried using fcolorbox{red}{white} but the second argument always paints over my figure.

Comment: @Kong Added colors

Answer (score 3):

If you use a `\frame`, `\fbox`, or `\framebox`, the problem would be, that some of the rules are drawn, before the content. So you would have to trim the content to avoid, that it is dawn above the already drawn rule. Another suggestion would be, to first draw the image and then draw a frame with the wanted size:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\imageheight}

\begin{document}
%\setlength{\fboxrule}{1ex}% Try to see what happens with fat rules

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}%
    \settoheight{\imageheight}{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}}%
    \fboxsep=0pt
    \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}\\
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}}%
    \raisebox{\fboxrule}{\framebox[\imagewidth]{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\imageheight-2\fboxrule}}}%
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you can clip the content by the rule width using package `trimclip`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,trimclip}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}%
    \fboxsep=0pt
    \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}\\
    \framebox[\imagewidth]{\clipbox{\fboxrule}{\includegraphics[width=
        \imagewidth]{example-image-a}}}\\
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{1ex}
    \fbox{\clipbox{\fboxrule}{\includegraphics[width=
        \imagewidth]{example-image-a}}}\\
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can additionally use `\color` before the `\fbox` or put the `\fbox` into a `\textcolor` command or replace `\fbox` by `\fcolorbox` to change the color of the frame:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,trimclip,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}%
    \fboxsep=0pt
    \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}\\
    \framebox[\imagewidth]{\clipbox{\fboxrule}{\includegraphics[width=
        \imagewidth]{example-image-a}}}\\
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{1ex}%
    \textcolor{green}{%
    \fbox{\clipbox{\fboxrule}{\includegraphics[width=
        \imagewidth]{example-image-a}}}}\\
    \fcolorbox{blue}{white}{\clipbox{\fboxrule}{\includegraphics[width=
      \imagewidth]{example-image-a}}}\\
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to use \textcolor and \frame. Better than fbox since it doesnt push the figures around.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definetrim}[2]{%
  \define@key{Gin}{#1}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{trim=#2,clip}}%
}
\makeatother

\definetrim{kit_mocap}{0 0 0 0} % {left bottom right top}
\def\barheight{0.015}
\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}
\def\imagehspace{\hspace{-0.2em}}
\def\imagevspace{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\textcolor{blue}{\frame{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagevspace

\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0] (image1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0] (image3) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image5) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image7) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image8) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagevspace

\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0] (image1) at (0,0) {\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image2) at (0,0) {\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0] (image3) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image5) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image7) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image8) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any reason why you're using a `tikzpicture` for each image rather than just setting them using `\includegraphics`? Seems completely unnecessary to have all that code that achieves the same thing.

Comment: `\frame` does not really expand the frame *inwards*. And it also does not use `\fboxrule`. If you already use `tikzpicture`, why not simply use a background rectangle with different colors (and even white)? Was your *real* question about how to get such a frame around `tikzpicture` with TikZ? Than you should ask this and not showing a cryptic `\frame` command and an example, that does not even use TikZ.